# Using something other than single or double quotes to set variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some hard coded text that contains many single quotes and double quotes.

```
text = "get in the "van" I said get in the 'van'"
```

I can escape each double quote with \ or I can switch to single quotes on the outside and escape each single quote.

What I'd like to do is just be able to pick something else, like !
Is there something simple I can do?  In Perl I was always able to:

```
text = qq!this will use "whatever" I'm happy with!
```

I'm using Python 3.6 if that helps.

Comment: You can use triple quotes: `text = """This will use "whatever" I'm happy with!"""`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I knew there had to be something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option to initialize a string is with `"""` or `'''`:

`text = """get in the "van" I said get in the 'van'"""`

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed.  I knew it had to be something simple!  I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Note that [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes) states: *"For triple-quoted strings, always use double quote characters to be consistent with the docstring convention in PEP 257 "*

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate multiple strings

```
text = 'get in the "van" I said get in the ' "'van'"
```